# setTimeout - callback argument must be a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, callback, settimeout

My code was working until i updated node.js to version 8.11.3

Now i always get error "callback argument must be a function"  when trying to call a function with setTimeout.

```
function testFunction(itemid, price) {

  var url = 'https://example.com';
  var options = {
  method: 'get',
  url: url
  }

  request(options, function (err, res, body) {
    var response = JSON.parse(body);

     if(response.status == 'fail'){
        setTimeout(testFunction(itemid, price), 100);
     }
  })

}
```

Comment: The code never worked as intended, FYI.

Comment: Agreed, @MHH, you probably just didn't notice that `testFunction` was not called after 100 ms, but rather immediately – you weren't passing the function `testFunction` as argument to `setTimeout`, but rather the result from calling it. Upgrading to Node 8.11.3 exposed your mistake, because it doesn't allow you to pass anything but a function anymore

Comment: Related: [How can I pass a parameter to a setTimeout() callback?](/q/1190642/4642212), [Calling functions with setTimeout()](/q/3800512/4642212), [Why is the method executed immediately when I use setTimeout?](/q/7137401/4642212).

Answer (score 16):

Callback argument for `setTimeout` must be a function. Write it like this. Not tested but it should work.

```
function testFunction(itemid, price) {

    var url = 'https://example.com';
    var options = {
        method: 'get',
        url: url
    }

    request(options, function (err, res, body) {
        var response = JSON.parse(body);
        if(response.status == 'fail'){
            setTimeout(function () {
                testFunction(itemid, price);
            }, 100);
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: *it always requires a function as the callback argument* - it doesn't. `setTimeout(<string>)` is a form of eval that was intentionally removed from Node implementation.

Comment: @estus Don't about that. Revoking that line.

Answer (score 10):

@keyur is correct. According to the [node.js timers documentation](https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/timers-in-node/) the setTimeout function takes the name of the function to execute as the first argument, the delay in milliseconds as the second argument, followed by any arguments being passed to the function.

For Example:

```
setTimeout(testFunction, 100, itemid, price);
```

Answer (score 4):

Yes, setTimeout() expects first argument as callback function.
we can make use of es6 fat arrow function here
you can try this!

```
setTimeout(() => testFunction(itemid, price), 100);
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

**Q:** I am getting the error "callback argument must be a function" when trying to call a function with setTimeout. Why?

**A:** `setTimeout(testFunction(itemid, price), 100);` You have accidentally pushed the output of `testFunction` as the first argument of `setTimeout` which it is suppose to be a `function` and hence the error.

What you could do is, pass in a function and call the `testFunction` recursively from there.

**Example:**

```js
function test(itemid, price) {
    console.log("hello => " + itemid + ", " + price);
    if (price < 50) {
      setTimeout(() => { test(itemid, price + 10) }, 100);    
    }
}

test(100, 10)
```