# The argument must be a function

Tags: javascript, node.js

I want to make a loop that downloads a file on an interval. But I can't make the setTimeout function work when the request function needs a parameter. It's the last line of the progam that i failing. What am I doing wrong?

```
const http = require('http');
const fs = require('fs');

const file = fs.createWriteStream("file.jpg");
const fileToDownload = "http://i3.ytimg.com/vi/J---aiyznGQ/mqdefault.jpg";

function request1() {
        http.get(fileToDownload, function(response) {
                response.pipe(file)
        });
}

function request2(saveName) {
        const save = fs.createWriteStream(saveName);

        http.get(fileToDownload, function(response) {
                response.pipe(save)
        });
}

setTimeout(request1, 3000);
setTimeout(request2("file2.jpg"), 3000); // TypeError: "callback" argument must be a function
```

Comment: You're passing the value *returned* by making a function call to `request2()`.

Comment: First find on google : [setTimeout - callback argument must be a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51685383/settimeout-callback-argument-must-be-a-function/51685407)) :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not passing a function, rather its result.
Use the following instead:

```
setTimeout(() => request2("file2.jpg"), 3000);
```

Comment: This is exactly what i wanted to comment :))

Answer (score 2):

Instead of passing a function to the `setTimeout` as it expects, you're passing a function call, which will take the parameter as the return type of the function instead of the function itself.

Instead you can just pass a function like -

```
setTimeout(() => request2("file2.jpg"), 3000);
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of calling function directly, try this:

```
setTimeout(function(){
  request2("file2.jpg")
}, 3000);
```

Or using arrow function

```
setTimeout(() => request2("file2.jpg"), 3000)
```